# Using a variable for column index in Vlookup?

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm trying to use Vlookup, but I need to do it so that the column index is a variable.  I tried everything, but so far I consistently get Invalid Qualifier errors.  I'd really appreciate if someone could ease me out of my stupidity.

```
Dim answer as Single
Dim col As Single
col = 2
answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Hello", A1:C50, (col.column), 0)
```

Specfically, I know the problem is with how I'm using the column variable, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Hello", [A1:C50], col, 0)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
...VLookup("Hello", ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C50"), col, 0)
```

However it would be better to use an explicit sheet codename (i.e. `Sheet1`) in place of the hazardous `Activesheet`.